Soft keyboard tab navigation across editable AG Grid cells
I can see on https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/keyboard-navigation/#example when I am editing a cell, I can press  on my laptop keyboard to edit the next editable cell.  However, on my mobile phone, the soft keyboard shows an  key which simply completes editing the current cell without navigating to another cell.
How can I get a  button which edits the next editable cell, like I have on input fields outside the grid?
